# Как задать метрику сетевому интерфейсу?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Есть ли какие либо стандартные или WinAPI способы считать и задать метрику сетевым интерфейсам?

Comment: Powershell подойдёт? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/set-netipinterface?view=win10-ps Можно вызвать из программы на C#.